# Xpath for button within a table with no html id

Tags: html, xpath, dynamic

Looking for xpath for attached piece of code. Here is the code snippet for the table

```
<table id="ManualPageButtonRowTop" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%" role="presentation">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td width="40%">
            &nbsp;
        </td>

        <td width="20%" align="center">
            <input type="button" value="Save" class="ButtonReq" tabindex="120" onclick="saveManualPage(); this.style.display = 'none'; showElementById('ButtonWithPleaseWait_MessageId_128'); setTimeout(function() { Dom.addClass('ButtonWithPleaseWait_MessageId_128', 'AjaxLoadingMessage') }, 100)"><span style="padding:4px; display:none" id="ButtonWithPleaseWait_MessageId_128">Processing request. Please wait...</span>
        </td>

        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: It is mandatory that you include code in a `code` section and **not** as image.

Comment: Also, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the attributes class or value, for example:

```
//table//input[@type='button'][@value='Save'][@class='ButtonReq']
```